# Selecionar dados em três tabelas MySQL e trazer o resultado mais recente com a soma

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, join

estou tentando juntar dados de três tabelas usando esse sql:

```
select c.NOME,c.CPF,e.DATA_CAD ,e.ENFERECO as ENDEREÇO_Atual , sum(f.VALOR)
from cli1 as c
inner join end1 as e 
on c.IDCLI1 = e.ID_END
inner join fat1 as f
on f.ID_FATEND1 = e.IDEND1
where CPF = '12345678912'
order by e.ENFERECO desc;
```

O problema é que ele retorna os dados com o primeiro endereço cadastrado, e eu queria retornar com o ultimo endereço cadastrado e a data de alteração referente ao mesmo e o valor total faturado.

Exemplo do resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso proceder neste caso?

Comment: se usar `order by e.DATA_CAD desc, e.ENFERECO desc`?

Comment: Dessa formar também não retorna com a data e o endereço mais recente, retorna o primeira data e endereço cadastrado com a soma dos valores faturado.

Comment: monta um exemplo com dados para ficar mais fácil de ajudar. Pode ser no sqlfiddle

Comment: Segue o Link [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddc813) `code`